# How Can I Get Parent ID in JQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to use closest with attr, but I can't get id.

```js
function checkID() {
  id = $(this).closest('div').attr('id');
  alert(id);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="preview-image" id="prv-img">
  <div class="preview-remove" data-name="${fileName}" onclick="checkID()" id="prv-rmv">&times;</div>
  <img src="/images/examplefile.png" alt="">
  <div class="preview-info" id="prv-inf">${fileName}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: How and where do you call `checkID()`? What ID do you want to get in the end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why it's not working is that in your `checkID()` function, `jQuery` don't know what `this` refer to, so use:

```
function checkID(obj) {
  var id = $(obj).closest('div').attr('id');
  alert(id);
}
```

and

```
onclick="checkID(this)"
```

**Demo**

```js
function checkID(obj) {
  var id = $(obj).closest('div').attr('id');
  alert(id);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="preview-image" id="prv-img">
  <div class="preview-remove" data-name="${fileName}" onclick="checkID(this)" id="prv-rmv">&times;</div>
  <img src="/images/examplefile.png" alt="">
  <div class="preview-info" id="prv-inf">${fileName}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Aren't our answers the same?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini True they are basically the same, only difference is that I've added some explanation why it's not working. I believe that it's better to explain why it's not working when you provide a solution

Comment: I did too, Not work because he don't specify element in the onclick call. :)

Comment: @SimoneRossaini from the time stamps of the two answers, it's clear they they were being written at the same time.  This happens.  There's no reason to delete one answer because someone else said the same thing (despite some bullying by people with very high rep).  Personally, I don't like your "how can you use...?" in an *answer* as it's demeaning to the questioner.   If they were worded identically, it would still be up to the OP which answer they accepted.

Comment: I just pointed out that there was no difference between the two answers, I don't think I've ever asked to delete anything

Comment: @SimoneRossaini One difference between our answers that that when you say `You must specify "this" in the onclick call then use it in the function` you tell the OP how to make it work, not explaining why it didn't work.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Probably in my vision it is the same thing, assuming that OP had a minimum of knowledge on the subject by explaining how it works you also explain the problem in 90% of cases, especially in these so simple things

Comment: I don't understand this "persistence" when I simply ask a question.
Also because as you can see the OP has chosen another answer

Comment: I don't understand why `Aren't our answers the same?` would event matter. Is our code the same? basically yes. Is the answer and explanation the same, no? Also as Freedom pointed out both answers where posted 7 seconds apart. I'm sorry if you got offended by anything. I'll Kill the discussion here from my part.

Comment: No no I was not offended, it seemed to me that I had raised an argument for nothing. :)

Answer (score 1):

How you can use `this` in function? You must specify "this" in the `onclick` call then use it in the function

```js
function checkID(el) {
        id = $(el).closest('div').attr('id');
        alert(id);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="preview-image" id="prv-img">
    <div class="preview-remove" data-name="${fileName}" onclick="checkID(this)" id="prv-rmv">&times;</div>
    <img src="/images/examplefile.png" alt="">
    <div class="preview-info" id="prv-inf">${fileName}</div>
</div>
```